# correspondence between non archimedean valuations and prime ideals

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ be a integer ring of a number field $K$.

It seems to be well known that there is a one to one correspondence between (non trivial?) non archimedean valuations of $K$ and (non zero?) prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$. But I didn't see detal.

Please tell me the accurate statement and a proof?

Comment: Let $K$ a field and $R$ a subring with fraction field $K$. From a principal maximal ideal $(\pi)$ of $R$ there is a unique corresponding discrete valuation $v(a) = n$ if $a \in \pi^n R,a\not\in(\pi^{n+1})$ and $R_{(\pi)}=O_v$. For a non-principal maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R=O_K$ what you need is to show it becomes principal in the localization $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$, which is equivalent to the factorization of ideals in product of maximal ideals (for example $(5,5i)$ doesn't become principal in $\Bbb{Z}[5i]_{(5,5i)}$ and there are two DVR $\Bbb{Z}[i]_{(2+i)},\Bbb{Z}[i]_{(2-i)}$ above it)

Comment: @reuns First of all, would you write down the statement (bijection) specifically and exactly? I worry about some well-definednesses of the maps before proving that.